# Multi Device Hybrid App in Visual Studio 2013 Does Not Refresh / Crashes

Tags: refresh, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I have created a multi device hybrid project in Visual Studio 2013.

I am having a few major issues:

1) Changes to my scripts do not appear unless I completely rebuild the application when I am using Ripple to view the project.

2) Pressing F12 in the Chrome ripple window causes Visual Studio to stop running the application.  This seems very strange. It's like if I were to quit debugging on a normal webapp.

Output shows `The program '[1] http://localhost:4400/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusGalaxy: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`

Has anyone had these problems or know what might be causing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the behaviors you describe are expected.  Ripple is not automatically refreshed when you save your changes so you will need to rebuild and deploy for it to pick up the updates.  Since only one process can use the webkit debugging at once, the VS debugging session gets disconnected when you use the debugging tools in Chrome.

Comment: Yikes! That stinks!  It takes about 2 minutes to build the application. Prevents me from making even minor changes to the CSS or HTML.  I guess I will stick to another solution.